# Display different content based on Select option value - PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display info based on what the user selects in drop down box and seems I cant get it working:

Here is what I did:

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['order-type'][0])){
$OrderType =  "small format black and white";
}

if(isset($_POST['order-type'][1])){
$OrderType =  "small format color";
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name="order-type">
  <option value="SmallFormatBW">Small Format Black & White</option>
  <option value="SmallFormatColor">Small Format Color</option>
</select>
```

Any help is high appreciated!
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select an `option` with the `value="SmallFormatBW"` from a `select` with `name="order-type"` and `POST` it to PHP. You will access it in PHP as `$_POST['order-type']` carrying the value `SmallFormatBW`.

```
$_POST['order-type'] == 'SmallFormatBW'
```

That means if you want to test the value, you would do it like this

```
if(!empty($_POST['order-type']) && ($_POST['order-type'] == 'SmallFormatBW')){
    $OrderType =  "small format black and white";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Comment: ;). I hope you can understand it.

Comment: Yup I do understand Now. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

If you use $_POST['order-type'] as array you must collect array from form. In your case you can try this.

```
<select name="order-type[]">
  <option value="SmallFormatBW">Small Format Black & White</option>
  <option value="SmallFormatColor">Small Format Color</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the solution but for some reason it didn't work for me.  I solved it the as frz3993 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a '$_GET' in the HTML I think...

look here for more info about submitting info from a PHP page to a HTML page:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (isset($_POST['order-type'])) {
    if($_POST['order-type'] == 'SmallFormatBW'){
        $OrderType =  "small format black and white";
    } else if($_POST['order-type'] == 'SmallFormatColor'){
        $OrderType =  "small format color";
    }
}
```